# Uncaught end of input in a search+button section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a page that takes a string and uses the Wikimedia API to search wikipedia for 10 relevant pages.
What my Javascript success function does is to populate the list with items according to the returned object 2(1 in zero index). the commented line stand for further addition of text and relevant link to the items.
My problem is that I can't find the cause for the Unexpected end of input problem. It is even more confusing to me because a similar code is working on a less complex test page that I made.

```js
function search() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
  data: {
   "action": "opensearch",
   "format": "json",
   "search": document.getElementById('search')
    .attributes[1].ownerElement.value,
   "namespace": "0",
   "limit": "10",
   "profile": "normal",
   "redirects": "return",
   "formatversion": "1"
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(resultObject) {
   //========POPULATE RESULTS AND SET TITLES
   for(let i = 0; i < resultObject[1].length; i++) {
    let liNode = document.createElement('LI');
    let anchorNode = document.createElement('A');
    let contentDivNode = document.createElement('DIV');
    let headNode = document.createElement('H3');
    let textDivNode = document.createElement('DIV');
    let headText = document.createTextNode(resultObject[1][i]);
    let textNode = document.createTextNode('');
    anchorNode.className = 'link';
    contentDivNode.className = 'content';
    headNode.className = 'title';
    textDivNode.className = 'text';
    textDivNode.appendChild(textNode);
    headNode.appendChild(headText);
    contentDivNode.appendChild(headNode);
    contentDivNode.appendChild(textDivNode);
    anchorNode.appendChild(contentDivNode);
    liNode.appendChild(anchorNode);
    document.getElementById('results')
     .appendChild(liNode);
   }
   //  for (let i = 0; i<resultObject[2].length; i++){
   //   $('#results').eq(i)
   //  }
   //  for (let i = 0; i<resultObject[3].length; i++){}
   // }
  }
 });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #4c4320, #5a4128, #633f36, #664145, #624553);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#header {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-content: center;
}

footer {
  background: inherit;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5%;
  width: 100% margin-top: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 20px 100px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

a.link {
  color: inherit;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
}

h3.title {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header">Wikipeida Viewer by Alon Parag</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cols-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <input id="search" type="search">
          <button onclick="function search()">search
        </div>
        <div class="cols-lg-2">
        </div>
        <div class="cols-lg-4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <ul id="results">
            <li>
              <a class="li
              nk">
                <div class="content">
                  <h3 class="title">Title</h3>lorem ipsum hello nurse</div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Alon Parag© 2018. All Rights Reserved</footer>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was in the  element as follows:
`<button onclick="function search()">search` 
the function in the onclick attribute is what caused the error. removing it solved the problem.